# Django rest framework browsable api with pre-filled post forms

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I need to redefine json objects each time I make post requests using django rest framework browsable api. is there any configuration to enable pre-filled forms ?

[image: Empty form problem]

Comment: What do you mean by pre filled ?

Comment: eg. when loading "api/persons" url I get a post form with a json object with empty values instead of blank raw data {"name": "", age:"", function:""}

Comment: looks like you've been messing with the way serializers are defined. What does your view looks like ?

Comment: I have updated the question to show the form I want to prefill with json object

Comment: you can use default values in your models....which may serve your need ...

Comment: it has no relation with raw json data